# Adding acronym in my document

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, declare

I have to add an acronym list in my document and for that I am using:

```
\usepackage[acronym,style=long3col]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
```

and

```
\newacronym{LOWERCASE LABEL}{UPPERCASE LABEL}{THE FULL TERM}\par
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms]
```

However I am getting an error:

```
\newacronym{LOWERCASE LABEL}{UPPERCASE LABEL}{THE FULL TERM}\par
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms]
```

Please can someone tell me what's wrong with my code. Please find the code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,MSc,wordcount,oneside,anon, left= 40mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 20mm]{muthesis}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\usepackage[acronym,style=long3col]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\graphicspath{ {pics/} }
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
{
\newacronym{LOWERCASE LABEL}{UPPERCASE LABEL}{THE FULL TERM}\par
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms]

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
%ieeetran}
\bibliography{references}

%\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.   You can highlight your code in-line by preceding and following it by a backtick.  To keep a separate code block formatted properly, highlight the block with your mouse, then click on the `{}` icon above the question box.

Comment: Do you get the same error with `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{glossaries} \begin{document} z \end{document}`?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some comments on your code:

1. `hyperref` should be loaded last [with a few exceptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/140456).
2. `\newacronym` should be used in the preamble of your document, after `\makeglossaries`. If you are going to define many entries it should be preferable to write them in a separate `.tex` file and include the file with `\input{...}` or better `\loadglsentries{...}` (again, after `\makeglossaries`)
3. You have a `\begin{titlepage}` without its corresponding `\end{titlepage}`.
4. There is a group starting after `\begin{document}` and ending after `\vspace*{1cm}` that does nothing but trouble.
5. Finally you have to use an acronym in order to print something. Remember that the compilation chain should be something like:

   pdflatex mydoc.tex

   makeglossaries mydoc

   pdflatex mydoc.tex

(`pdflatex` could be changed for your favorite TeX flavor)

An example on how to add acronyms to your document is the following

```
\documentclass[12pt,MSc,wordcount,oneside,anon, left= 40mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 20mm]{muthesis}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym,style=long3col]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{svm}{SVM}{Support Vector Machine}

\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\graphicspath{ {pics/} }
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms]

\chapter{test}
Hello world!

First use of acronym \gls{svm}. Second use \gls{svm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However I am still getting the same error.



Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\base\glossaries.sty"
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \DeclareRelease 
                                
l.42 \DeclareRelease
                    {v4.46}{2020-03-19}{glossaries-2020-03-19.sty}
?

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on with your installation. In my local installation, the code runs as expected, I also tried in [TeXlive](https://texlive.net/) (adding `automake` option to `glossaries`) and overleaf and, again, runs as expected. Since I'm not very skillful, I suggest asking a new question containing the details in your comment and I hope you can find a solution to your problem

Comment: Thanks Luis for your reply. I am still not able to figure out the problem. Is there anyone else who can help me please.